# How to select the last action of a user

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following DataFrame `df`:

```
customer_id   product_id   timestamp   action
111           1            1519030817  add
111           1            1519030917  remove
111           2            1519030819  add
222           2            1519030819  add
```

I want to group records by `customer_id` and `product_id`, and take the last action.

This is what I did:

```
df.groupBy("customer_id","product_id").orderBy(desc("timestamp"))
```

But how can I actually take the latest action?

The result should be the following:

```
customer_id   product_id   timestamp   action
111           1            1519030917  remove
111           2            1519030819  add
222           2            1519030819  add
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Window` function as below

```
  val w = Window.partitionBy("customer_id", "product_id")
          .orderBy(desc("timestamp"), desc("action"))

  df.withColumn("rn", row_number().over(w))
          .where($"rn" === 1).drop("rn") show (false)
```

Output:

```
+-----------+----------+----------+------+
|customer_id|product_id|timestamp |action|
+-----------+----------+----------+------+
|111        |2         |1519030819|add   |
|222        |2         |1519030819|add   |
|111        |1         |1519030917|remove|
+-----------+----------+----------+------+
```